# Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint when executing Lambda based on Docker Image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a lambda function using CDK, when the stack is deployed, I hit the api and see the following error in my lambda function

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 5afa8a81-6eb3-4293-a57c-e8c6472ddff4 Error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error"
}
```

My lambda function looks like

```
import { Context, APIGatewayProxyResult, APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`);
    console.log(`Context: ${JSON.stringify(context, null, 2)}`);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'hello world',
        }),
    };
};
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like below

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json index.ts ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist/* ./
CMD ["index.handler"]
```

and my stack deploys as following

```
const fakeFunction = new aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, 'FakerFunction', {
            code: aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
                path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'functions', 'fakedata')
            ),
        });

        const integration = new HttpLambdaIntegration('FakerIntegration', fakeFunction);
        const httpApi = new apigw2.HttpApi(this, 'HttpApi', {
            apiName: 'fake-api',
            createDefaultStage: true,
            corsPreflight: {
                allowMethods: [CorsHttpMethod.GET],
                allowOrigins: ['*'],
                maxAge: Duration.days(10)
            }
        });

        httpApi.addRoutes({
            path: '/fake',
            methods: [HttpMethod.GET],
            integration: integration
        })

        new CfnOutput(this, 'API Endpoint', {
            value: httpApi.url!
        })
```

My code is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/typescript-cdk/tree/h2/api-query. You need to run `cdk deploy` to deploy this stack.

I am not sure what am I missing and what I need to do to fix this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify the `Platform` in order to resolve this issue. Specifically, I had to use `Platform.LINUX_AMD64` as defined below

```
import {Platform} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr-assets";

const fakeFunction = new aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, 'FakerFunction', {
            code: aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
                path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'functions', 'fakedata'),
                {
                    platform: Platform.LINUX_AMD64
                }
            ),
        });
```